# Terminal stops Connection to Safari

Tags: safari, macos-mojave

I want to open Safari, but in Terminal it throws the error: LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/Safari.app. 
I have tried some of the solutions from the past (also from Stack overflow) but none of them worked. Does anybody know how to fix this issue so that i can use Safari properly?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How are you opening Safari? Are you using `open http://example.com/`?

Comment: No I Open safari directly: open /Applications/Safari.app or i navigate through the Applications dir with cd /Applications

Comment: When asking questions here try and be specific about what you're doing otherwise we need to guess. For some reason it sounds like your Safari is trashed. Can you open other applications (e.g. Chrome?) this way?

Comment: Sorry, but this stack oflow restriction ai doesnt let me Write any coherant phrase. Yes i can open other Apps like chrome,... but i Not a bash shell Expert so i Cant repair it myself